# Why isn't this println being executed with the entire body?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm new to programming and trying to understand this nested for loop completely. The `println` is part of the body of the inner loop. However, it is not being executed with the inner loop iteration. I don't want to execute it, but I'm just trying to understand why the inner loop body isn't executed completely?

```
int rowNum, colNum;
    for (rowNum = 1; rowNum <= 3; rowNum++) 
    {
     for (colNum = 1; colNum <= 2; colNum++) 
            System.out.print(" rowNum: " + rowNum + " colNum: " + colNum);
        System.out.println();

    }
```

If the println() were executed with the body I would get something like this:

```
 rowNum: 1 colNum: 1
 rowNum: 1 colNum: 2
 rowNum: 2 colNum: 1
 rowNum: 2 colNum: 2
 rowNum: 3 colNum: 1
 rowNum: 3 colNum: 2
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
 rowNum: 1 colNum: 1 rowNum: 1 colNum: 2
 rowNum: 2 colNum: 1 rowNum: 2 colNum: 2
 rowNum: 3 colNum: 1 rowNum: 3 colNum: 2
```

Again, I just want to understand why, not how to fix it... Thanks!

Comment: No the println is part of the outer loop, as you don't use curly braces! Thus only the first print belongs to the inner loop.

Comment: Everything would be obvious if you indented the code properly. Use your IDE "format code" action to do that for you, and you *will* spot such bugs, because the structure of the code will become clear. And always, always use curly braces around blocks, even is they contain a single instruction.

Comment: @GhostCat Right, I noticed that once I added the curly braces, the println became part of the inner loop body. So, the confirmation is that if I don't add curly braces to the body of a loop, then only the first line is part of that body, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Totally agree with "fix your indentation."  Everything would be clear if you did that.  The `println` is NOT part of the inner loop body.

Comment: Guys, I'm not trying to fix anything. This is a code from a textbook. I am new to this. I was just trying to understand why the println wasn't part of the body. Remember you guys have been doing this for awhile, sometimes somethings are obvious for experience coders, not the same for newbies --even if things are indented property. BUT thanks for the indentation tip, I'll certainly apply it and I just went through my IDE format on save actions :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for loop execute only next 1 line if curly brackets are not provided. if you give curly brackets between second for loop and after println();.
you will get want you want.

System.out.print(" xxx ");
        System.out.println();

this will give you
xxx  xxx
xxx  xxx

because it is print println
print 2 times then line comes.

edit first System.out.println(" rowNum: " + rowNum + " colNum: " + colNum);

and remove second println.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This shows convincingly how to fix things, but the original question was about why the second println wasn't executed as part of the internal for loop. By the way, you can use triple backticks (```) to format your code for future answers.

Comment: because for loop execute only next 1 line if curly brackets are not provided. if u give curly brackets between second for loop and after println();. you will get how you want.

Answer (score -1):

rowNum: 1 colNum: 1 rowNum: 1 colNum: 2 rowNum: 2 colNum: 1 rowNum: 2 colNum: 2 rowNum: 3 colNum: 1 rowNum: 3 colNum: 2

This is because you print 2 times before getting out of the loop and print a new line.

Comment: this is very vague. please improve upon your answer. currently the comments to the OP are much more detailed in answering the question.